# Android calculator can't solve some equations

Tags: c#, android

Hello guys I have this android calculator am working on,it contains 2 textviews named, calculator(where all calculations takes place,the visibilty is set to invincible) and texview(displays the equations). The arithmetic operators seem to be working well e.g 3+3+5= 11 ,5+5-1=9, 5/5-1=0. The problem am having is whenever the equations look like the above examples it gives the correct answers but when I have stuffs like 3-2+1, 5/5+1, 2*2/4 I get very wrong answers. The codes for the relevant buttons are...

```
        button1.Click += delegate {
            textveiw.Text += button1.Text;
            calculator.Text += button1.Text;
            if (equalToClick==true){
                total1=0;
                total2=0;
                calculator.Text="";
                calculator.Text += button1.Text;
                textveiw.Text=button1.Text;
                equalToClick=false;
            }
        };
        plus.Click += delegate {
        textveiw.Text += plus.Text;            
   total1=total1+double.Parse
   (calculator.Text);
        calculator.Text=("");
            equalToClick=false;
         operatorSelected="+";
            plusClick=true;

        };
        sub.Click += delegate {
            textveiw.Text += sub.Text;    
    total1=total1+double.Parse
    (calculator.Text);
            calculator.Text=("");
            equalToClick=false;
            operatorSelected="-";
            subClick = true;
         };
        multiplication.Click += delegate {
        textveiw.Text += multiplication.Text;
        total1= total1+double.Parse
   (calculator.Text);
         calculator.Text=("");
         equaltoclick=false;
         operatorSelected="*";
         mulClick = true;

        };
        divide.Click += delegate {
            textveiw.Text += divide.Text;
            total1 = total1 + double.Parse
     (calculator.Text);
            calculator.Text=("");
            equalToClick=false;
            operatorSelected="/";
            divClick = true;

        };
        //equals button
        equalto.Click+=delegate {
            switch(operatorSelected)
            {

            case "+" :
                total2=total1+double.Parse
       (calculator.Text);
                textveiw.Text=total2.ToString();
                equalToClick=true;
                plusClick=false;
                break;

            case "-":
                total2=total1 - double.Parse
       (calculator.Text);
                textveiw.Text=total2.ToString();
                equalToClick=true;
                subClick=false;
                break;
            case "*":
                total2=total1 * double.Parse
       (calculator.Text);
                textveiw.Text=total2.ToString();
                equalToClick=true;
                mulClick=false;
                break;

             case "/":

                total2=total1 / double.Parse
       (calculator.Text);
                textveiw.Text=total2.ToString();
                equalToClick=true;
                divClick=false;
                break;

                default :
                if(subClick==false && 
         plusClick==false && 
        mulClick==false && 
        divClick==false){
                    Toast.MakeText
   (this,"please select an   
   operator",ToastLength.Short)
   .Show();
                }
                break;

                }
            };

        cancel.Click += delegate {
            textveiw.Text=("");
            calculator.Text=("");
            total1=0;
            total2=0;


        };
```

Comment: If you are allowing the entire equation as input before computing, your algorithm bust be smart to deal with BODMAS principals.

Comment: Can you share an insight on the smart algorithm if u don't mind